# Blinking in JFrame Java

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, java-2d

Hello guys I am doing a thread to update a ball over JFrame so I repaint the screen... and then paint the ball update its position .. and then draw the screen again ... draw the ball and the same cycle ... here is the code

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   Thread t = new Thread()
   {
     public void run()
     {
         while(true)
         {
             repaint();
             b2.update(ob,2);
             b2.paint(ob.getGraphics());

             b2.setT(b2.getT() + 1);
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(50);
             } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                 System.out.println("Error in Sleeping");
             }

         }
     }
   };

   t.start();
}
```

but the problem is that I don't see the ball... the paint of the screen always overrides the ball and the ball is like down under the Jframe ..

Comment: What is the type of your b2 and ob variables? I'm thinking that the problem might be because you're calling SWING code outside of the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). It's fine to call repaint outside the EDT (repaint is one of the few exceptions), but if b2 is a swing (or awt) component, it isn't fine to call its methods outside the EDT.

Comment: the b2 variable is an instance of public class Ball extends JApplet which is the ball itself ..
the ob variable is a refernce of the jframe object .. I send it to the ball to detrmine the height and the width of the frame to avoid going out of the boundries ..
U know what ... when I comment this line
repaint(); 
the ball shows up but over the jframe and the jframe didn't get updated which is expected .. but once I add it .. the ball disappear ... !!

Comment: You should not handle GUI updating tasks outside the EDT

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have animations in Swing, the recommended class to use is the `javax.swing.Timer` . This class allows you to perform operations on the Event Dispatch Thread at regular intervals.

- The [Swing `Timer` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- An [animation example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9849950/1076463) posted here on SO (which is linked in the Swing wiki here on SO btw)

Comment: You could also use SwingWorker.

Comment: @2012-EndoftheWorld SwingWorker is over kill for this problem

Comment: +1 for `javax.swing.Timer`, which conveniently encapsulates the sleeping.

Answer (score 3):

**Some General Rules**

- Swing is not thread safe, you should only ever update UI components from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.
- You do not control the paint process, the repaint manager does.  You can request updates to occur by calling `repaint`, but you should never call `update` and `paint` directly when trying to update the display.
- The `Graphics` context used by the paint sub system is a shared resource and is not guaranteed to be the same between paint cycles, you should never maintain a reference to it.  You should also not rely on the results from `JComponent#getGraphics` this method is capable of returning null.

**An Example Solution**

You have a number of options, depending on what you want to ultimately achieve.

You could use a `SwingWorker`, but given the fact that all your going to do is enter an infinite loop, it would easier to use `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` rather then actually using the `publish` method, as such, this approach would actually be more work.

You could also use a `Thread`, but you'd end up with the same problems as using a `SwingWorker`

The simpliset solution, for what you've presented, is actually a `javax.swing.Timer`

```
public class Blinky {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Blinky();
    }

    public Blinky() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new BlinkyPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    protected class BlinkyPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel blinkyLabel;
        private boolean blink = false;

        public BlinkyPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            blinkyLabel = new JLabel("I'm blinking here");
            blinkyLabel.setBackground(Color.RED);
            add(blinkyLabel);

            Timer timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    blink = !blink;
                    if (blink) {
                        blinkyLabel.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
                    } else {
                        blinkyLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                    blinkyLabel.setOpaque(blink);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 100);
        }

    }

}
```

You can take a look at [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

If you access GUI components outside the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) then you might encounter strange problems, Contrary if you perform long running tasks in the EDT then also you will get problems.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507685/gui-threading-in-java-and-swingutilities) post for more info on `GUI Threading in Java`

Comment: nop it is not working .. it is as if I am painting the ball but there is no repaint to the screen .... so I still see the trace of the ball in the screen .... like I see the places of the ball where it was... and they aren't deleted ... which not what I want ..

Comment: calling `Thread.sleep` on the EDT is not-done as it will block the whole UI. Use the `javax.swing.Timer` class if you want animations in Swing