# JComponent change bar color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jcomponent

I have a problem with my Component in Java. When i set OVF flag to true, Rect should be in Color red (255,0,0), and if i set OVF flag to false, Rect should be in color blue (0,0,255). The problem is that I can see in my GUI only blue rectangle (even if OVF flag is set to true). What should I change in this code?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Komponent2 extends JComponent implements ActionListener
{
Timer tm = new Timer(10, this);
int x =30;
int y =0, y2 = 8;
Counter counter3;
Color Kolor = new Color(255,255,255);

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
  counter3=new Counter();
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.setColor(Kolor);
  g.fillRect(y,30,x,30);
  tm.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
if(y<0 || y>300)
y2=-y2;
y=y + y2;
if (counter3.OVF==true)
Kolor = new Color (255,0,0);
if (counter3.OVF==false)
Kolor = new Color (0,0,255);
repaint ();
}
}
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Your code needs an emergency indentation.

Comment: Probably has something to do with how you are instantiating a new counter3 in every call to `paintComponent`.  Where are you setting OVF?

Comment: OVF is setting in Counter class. OVF is set to true when MainReg is set to 0 (it works, because if OVF==true i can see in my GUI class label "INTERRUPT"

Comment: Swing Timer repeats. Y default, so calling start in paintComponent probably isn't a good idea

Comment: You might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779392/blinking-in-jframe-java/13781606#13781606) out for some more ideas

Comment: So where should I put start of timer?

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Create a constructor in the `Komponent2` class containing the counter initialization and start the `Timer`. This will prevent multiple instances of `Counter` being created. Also move the `Timer` from the `paintComponent` method so that it is not restarting for every repaint.

```
public Komponent2() {
   counter3 = new Counter();
}

public void init() {
   tm.start();
}
```

Comment: Now my Rectangle is still white. It looks like timer doesn't starts.

Comment: Did you call the new `init` method to start it?

Comment: I just add lines "public void init () { tm.start(); }". And I removed tm.start(); from paintComponent

Comment: Where and how should I call this method to start it?

Comment: Just after you make the main `JFrame`/application visible

Comment: My rectangle is still blue, even if OVF==true.