# Thread help. Paint

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, java-2d, japplet

Can someone please help me with the comment lines except the ones where it asks to delete things. Thank you!

```
public class ex1011c extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
        // get rid of all winkbutton code

    JButton winkbutton = new JButton("Wink At You");
    boolean wink = false, first = true;
    Container c;

    public void init()
    {
        c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        c.setBackground(Color.blue);
        winkbutton.setForeground(Color.cyan);
        c.add(winkbutton);
        winkbutton.addActionListener(this);
    }

        // get rid of actionPerformed

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        wink = !wink;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        /* if first time, draw the face and non winking eye,
            set first to false */

        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(50, 50, 100, 100);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillOval(85, 80, 10, 20);

        /* cover just the eye that winks (if winking or not, but do not
         cover anything else), switch the wink boolean */

        // draw the full eye or winking eye

        if (wink)
            g.fillOval(105, 88, 10, 5);
        else
            g.fillOval(105, 80, 10, 20);

        // go to sleep for a second

        // call repaint
    }

        // override update to lesson flicker

}
```

Comment: Don't put logic in a paint event.  Instead, use a timer and store the state.

Comment: @raffian throughout the code there's comment lines on things to do. I'm stuck on them. I'd appreciate any help

Comment: *"I'm stuck on them."*  What tutorials have you looked through?  What have you tried?  Where *exactly* are you stuck?  Note that a good SO question should have one question with one or more answers to that one question.  What you've posted amounts to a 'shopping list'.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, don't sleep/pause/block or otherwise impede the Event Dispatching Thread.

The EDT, is amongst other things, responsible for process paint requests, anything to stops it from running (like `Thread.sleep`) will stop it from updating the screen.

Remember, just because you paint something to the `Graphics` context, doesn't mean it gets rendered to the output.

Instead, use a `javax.swing.Timer`

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.

I would also, strongly, encourage you against overriding any `paint` method of a top level container like `JApplet`.  Instead, use something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method instead.

Apart from potability, you gain the benefit of double buffering which top level containers don't have...

For example...

- [Blinking in JFrame Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779392/blinking-in-jframe-java/13781606#13781606)

**With simple example**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Blinky {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Blinky();
    }

    public Blinky() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new BlinkPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class BlinkPane extends JPanel {

        private boolean wink;

        public BlinkPane() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    wink = !wink;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - 10) / 2;
            int eyeHeight = 20;
            if (wink) {
                eyeHeight = 5;
            }
            int y = (getWidth() - eyeHeight) / 2;
            g.fillOval(x, y, 10, eyeHeight);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I reduce Flickering?

Comment: Use `JPanel` (override it's `paintComponent` method, do you custom painting there), add it to you applet, flickering gone...